# Delete file from Google Drive using Google Drive API SDK

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

How do I delete any file from Drive using Python's Google Drive API SDK?

I want to sync my folder with google drive, such that, whenever I delete any file from my local machine, the same file which is uploaded on the drive with same name, should be deleted.

I went through :  https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/delete

But then, from where do I get fileid?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The google drive windows app already does that. What do you mean by where do you get the id? If you are creating these files you have the id. Otherwise seach by title thou thats slower and consumes more quotas.

Comment: @ZigMandel: Deleting a file through the API skips the trash -- second line of description. This is useful to prevent the trash folder from consuming unnecessary disk space.

Comment: bro, I am trying to do programatically using Python, and trying to automate it. I am not looking for Google App Software being installed on my machine, and then syncing it.

Comment: there is a function called delete provided by Google in their API...how do I use it in my program?
and I won't be having file ids' with me, I want it to find by my file name, how do I do that?

Comment: Like I said search by file title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read and understand https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource and https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters and https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

At the bottom of the last page is a Try It Now feature which you can use to play with the Drive SDK **BEFORE** you write a single line of code. Do the same with https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/delete

Once you understand them, you will know how to trash or delete files from Drive. Personally I prefer trash as it's easier to undo my mistakes during testing. @martineau Don't worry too much about the disk space; Google isn't about to run out of disk :-)

The only catch to using Trash is you need to remember to qualify any queries with 'trashed=false' and users will need to empty Trash if ever they hit quota.